# White page on joomla template

Tags: php, joomla

I'm relatively new to Joomla so forgive me if this is a simple question. Anyway, I was given a template made from scratch to work on. This template has multiple pages such as index(obviously), blog and contact. My problem is aside from the index, none of my other layouts for the template appear. All I get is a white page. I'm suspecting it has something to do with my url (.../joomlaproj/templates/mytemplate/contact.php) Is there something I should add or change on my php file to make them appear. I've tried moving the contact and blog files outside the template folder but it still appears as an empty page. Why is this happening?

Comment: Its very difficult to tell you the reason for this beahviour until we see the website. The reason can be .htaccess, file folders permission, false coding , non compatible plugin and many more...So can you post your project URl obviously if its on live server

Comment: Sorry, the project's on localhost so there's really nothing I can share. I don't know if this helps but, the template was made from scratch. Not downloaded. I just can't access the layout of the other pages in the template I'm using. Why, I'm not sure. Anyway, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have misunderstood what Joomla is and how it works. It's a Content Management System and thus does not produce a static like website with simple PHP pages. You **don't** add each file such as *contact.php* and *blog.php* to the templates folder. You install an extension from the [Joomla Extensions Directory](http://extensions.joomla.org/) according to what you require, create a menu item via the backend and assign the component to it.

Take a look at the Joomla docs to give you more details overview of it:

http://docs.joomla.org/Getting_Started_with_Joomla!

If you were given a choice of what to use for this project such as Joomla, Wordpress, custom coded etc, then have a quick think about how big the site is going to be. If it primarily a blogging site which will also include a contact form, then your best choice might be Wordpress. If it will contain more, such as a forum or any other more complex systems, then Joomla will be your best bet.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. You're right. I misunderstood that part of Joomla. So the best approach I opt to do is create a separate template for the other pages, yes?

Comment: no, not a separate template. Install an extension from the website I provided you with first, then go to `Menus > Main Menu > New`....create a new menu link and assign that component to it

Comment: I'm not sure why you are saying to install an extension ... if he has something special he wants to do for contacts he would just do a layout override for that.

Comment: I didnt mean specifically for a contact page, I simple meant in general

Answer (score 1):

Besides reading the beginner documents and some documents on how to  make a template, you should look at the core templates.

If it is a Joomla template your template should go into the templates/yourtemplatename folder and you should install it using discover install. But if you have not been given an xml file for it that is not going to work. The fact that you don't mention an xml file indicates to me that you do not have a Joomla template.

Joomla templates do have an index.php file, but you should open the file and see if the file looks anything like the Protostar or Beez index.php files.  A Joomla template would possibly have a blog.php file which might be used to override the blog layout from Joomla and this file should look very similar to what you find in /components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog.php.  It would be placed in the templates/mytemplatename/html/com_content/category folder.

Next you need to separate how you are thinking about content an how you are thinking about design.

Selecting one of the default templates (protostar in Joomla 3) set up your content. That is create your home page article, your contact page, and your blog page (with some sample content). Connect each of these to your navigation, and in general get the content working the way you want. Then using the design specifications you have been given you may need to create a layout override that matches it.

What is it that the contact.php file contains? You should show some code.

Comment: It looks a bit different as the template I'm using uses less php than the Protostar index.php file. Actually, I just added the <jdoc:include> part to add the positions on the template in joomla so I don't think it's a Joomla template. The contact.php is an actual contact page with email, map, addresses etc. It's a static page. Anyway, I managed to resolve my problem by creating separate templates for each menu item. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: For the contact page you should use the contact component that is part of core Joomla.

Comment: Thanks. It's exactly what I did after trying to "fix" the template.